# Run selenium test case using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

am working on selenium framework. so i want to build my test cases based on excel data and i need to trigger separate child build for each test cases. Do you have any approach or Jenkins plugin to achieve. here am not going to use TestNG.[image: This is Test data]

i want to trigger a build it should run all my test cases with separate build not a single build. do we have any plugins to achieve this?

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please add more details like what kind of project you have. Maven? Is it stored in any repository like github?

Comment: Yes, am using maven project